# aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientConnectorError: Cannot connect to host example.com:port ssl:default [Connect call failed ('IP', PORT)]

Tags: python-3.x, aiohttp

I'm making requests to find out a status.

The requests should be sent until that status is reached, however, when it exceeds 25 "simultaneous" connections it gives a connection error, I've already tried setting `ssl=False` and also using `sslcontext`, I tried `aiohttp.connector(limit=1000, limit_per_host=1000)`
honestly nothing worked

remembering that below 25 requests it works correctly

```
import aiohttp
import asyncio
import sys

if sys.platform == 'win32':
    asyncio.set_event_loop_policy(asyncio.WindowsSelectorEventLoopPolicy())


async def proccess_status(headers, payload):
    await asyncio.sleep(0.3)

    async with aiohttp.ClientSession(connector=aiohttp.TCPConnector(limit=10000, limit_per_host=10000), trust_env=True) as session:
        while True:
            async with session.post("https://example.com", headers=headers, data=payload) as response:
                try:
                    #print(response)
                    pass
                
                except Exception as error:
                    print(error)


async def main():
    number_of_requests = 50
    timeout = 18000  # Timelimit in seconds
    headers = {}
    payload = "random_payload"

    tasks = [asyncio.create_task(proccess_status(headers, payload)) for _ in range(number_of_requests)]
    
    results, pending_tasks = await asyncio.wait(tasks, return_when=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED, timeout=timeout)
    
    if results:
        first_task_done = results.pop()
        value = first_task_done.result()
    else:
        print("No requests were completed within the time limit.")
    
    for task in pending_tasks:
        task.cancel()

    return value


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

what i expected:

```
<ClientResponse(https://example.com) [200 OK]>
<CIMultiDictProxy('Connection': 'close', 'Content-Length': '371', 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*', 'Content-Encoding': 'br', 'Date': 'Sun, 21 Jan 2024 17:02:57 GMT', 'Timing-Allow-Origin': '*')>
```

what i got:

```
aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientConnectorError: Cannot connect to host example.com:port ssl:default [Connect call failed ('IP', PORT)]
```

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little vague on exactly what you want to achieve. But, if it's simply limiting it to 25 simultaneous requests, then just adding a semaphore could work as a quick solution.

```
async def process_status(headers, payload, sem):
    async with sem:
        ...

async def main():
    sem = asyncio.Semaphore(25)
    tasks = (asyncio.create_task(process_status(headers, payload, sem) for ...)
```

Note that this still creates all the tasks in memory, so a better solution would likely involve some kind of queue which only creates 25 tasks at any given time.

Comment: I have several sites to check the status, so I can't limit myself to just 25 simultaneous requests, I've tried semaphores too, but unfortunately they didn't work the way I needed, do you think there's a way to remove this limitation somehow?

Comment: It's still not clear what you need to achieve. If you want to send all the requests and not get an error, then you probably want to figure out what is causing the error (e.g. which server). If it's caused by a server that you previously sent a request to, then it might be misbehaving and closing a keep-alive connection immediately after sending a response. In which case the issue might be solved in 3.10 by https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/pull/8038. Until that is released, you might try `force_close=True`: https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_reference.html#aiohttp.BaseConnector

Comment: its not a server and unfortunaly, force_close=True didn't help me in that case
idk why, but, if i edit the "number_of_requests" to 25, i dont get this error, but, with only 25 requests, the efficiency is worse, so, i need more than 25 simultaneous requests